# Necesito si me pueden ayudar a hacer una expresión regular en javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito hacer una expresión regular en javascript que pueda Aceptar La primera letra obligatoria en Mayúsculas, el resto en minúsculas, ademas que pueda aceptar acentos, la letra ñ y Ñ,  y comillas simples. Ya que, se usara para un formulario, ejemplo:

Rafael Andrés De'lukás Ibañez

Se los agradecería mucho de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: const pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/); esa expresion regular que me permite letras mayusculas, Minusculas, espacio en blanco, pero me faltan los acentos, la ñ minuscula y mayusculas y la comilla simple

Comment: Hola, agrega eso que comentas a la pregunta, por favor. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Recuerda que toda la información adicional debe ir en la pregunta, no en los comentarios. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Creo que esta expresión se ajusta a tus necesidades
la primera parte ^[A-Z] asegura que la primera letra sea mayúscula y al final se agregan los caracteres "raros" que deseas verificar Ñ-ñ'

```
/^[A-Z][A-Za-zÁ-ú'\s]+$/
```

Comment: El rango `[Ñ-ñ]` captura todos los caracteres ASCII extendidos desde el código 209 al 241. Por favor revisa tu respuesta, el rango plantedo deja por fuera al menos el símbolo `ó` y el símbolo `ú`, entre otros. Saludos

Comment: No se deben responder preguntas mal planeadas.